# Installing Peerjs with npm results in warning

Tags: node.js, npm, peerjs

I am trying to use Peerjs as a simple chat interface between to clients in a local network. When trying to install Peerjs on win10 I get 4 warnings after the install command has ran. I included a screenshot to clarify. I attempt to run the server regardless hoping the warnings were not serious but alas it does not run.

Any help would be great!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBowH.png)

Comment: hi man! welcome to StackOverflow! Add your node.js and npm version please

Answer (score 1):

Those warnings are informing you that you haven't filled all the info fields in package.json (if, for example, you'd like to publish your work later to npm, that info would come in handy). In other words those warnings are not to worry about.

But there's another issue - you really shouldn't install anything inside of your Windows system folders, like C:\Windows\system32 or C:\Program Files\ There will be problems with access permissions.

Make a dedicated folder for your project, like C:\Users\Aaron\Projects\Peer.js\ and work there.

There may be other issues why server won't run, but you must address that one above first.